# Is it possible to represent two time series as a common and different component?

Tags: correlation, time-series

First of all, thank you for reading my question.

I would like to know if it is possible to rearrange two correlated time series as the sum of two individual components plus a a third common component? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind? Do you have any examples where you have shown you *can* separate them in the desired way but you haven’t been able to prove it mor generally?

Comment: You're not telling us everything you want these "components" to do. As stated, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the two original series you could use $S_1$ and $S_2$ for the "two individual components" and $0$ for the "common component" - surely that doesn't solve the problem you had in mind,  but it _does_ answer the question that you _asked_...

Comment: Thanks for your question, Clayton. I have no specific example. I was just curious. But maybe something like this might work. Lets imagine I would like to know the impact of monthly interest rates and the exhange rate on the volume of stocks traded in market. Monthly interest rates and exchange rates are usually highly correlated. In such case I would like to be able to separate the common effect from both variables, plus the individual effect of each variable on the dependent variable.